# ServiceWorker not intercepting calls immediately after installation

Tags: service-worker, service-worker-events

I am playing around with ServiceWorkers, and I noticed that even after a successful registration, the service worker is not intercepting calls

my sw.js:

```
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
    console.log('install')
})

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    console.log('activate')
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  console.log('fetch')
})
```

in my index.html:

```
...
<head>
...
<script>
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js', { scope: './' }).then(() => {
        // just delay it so we're sure sw is active before we load that script
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('load jsx script to be intercepted')
            const script = document.createElement('script')
            script.setAttribute('src', 'test.js')
            document.head.appendChild(script)
        }, 2000)
    })
</script>
...
</head>
...
```

Result:
My console output from the first page load, when service worker is not yet installed, is then (in that order):

```
install
activate
load jsx script to be intercepted
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

The syntax error is because I'm trying to load a JSX script, and I would like to intercept that loading in the service worker, to compile it first before it gets executed.

But on the initial load, the service worker seems to not intercept, as I don't see the log output 'fetch', although I clearly see, when I attempt to load the jsx script, by that time the service worker is already active.

When I now reload the page, I get following console output:

```
fetch     (<-- that's the loading of the index.html itself)
load jsx script that should be intercepted
fetch     (<-- that's the loading of the test.js)
```

So from then on, things work out as planned, but not on the initial load. Why is that the case?

Comment: You'll need to wait until the service worker is [installed and activated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#basic_architecture), not just until it is registered, before loading the `test.js` script.

Comment: @Bergi how to do that? In the page you listed it is explained how you can add an eventListener _inside_ the service worker itself, but I failed to do that outside like in the index.html.
But even when I tried inside, I can clearly see the service worker didn't even get activated on the first load. It seems I have to load the page a second time before the service-worker really gets activated. That seems strange - or is that normal?

Comment: What seems even more strange - even if I unregister the service worker in chrome and reload my page, the service worker does not really get updated. it still displays an old version of sw.js!

Comment: ok somehow I got the worker activated already on the first page load...still the problem remains - the service worker will not intercept calls from the first page load. I will update code snippet accordingly

Answer (score 0):

After some research it seems I was able to solve the problem using the related  post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53483592/fetch-event-not-getting-executed-in-very-first-time-page-load-in-service-worker), plus the [documentation of the "claim" api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim).

So if I add the following to my 'active' handler, things seem to work:

```
self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim())
```

I would appreciate any feedback on whether this is indeed the right way to go about it :-)